# issue releted to memoryleak in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using instruments tools for finding memory leaks in my application but unable to figure out where is the actual problem and  instruments tools for leak is showing leak in this class.

```
-(IBAction) GoToNext:(id)sender{


    ////NSLog(@"iPad");
    NextClass *sampleView = [[[NextClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    sampleView.ImageName = @"Tutorial.png";
    sampleView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
    [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
    sampleView.Title.text = @"On Christianity";
 }
```

NextClass.h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NextClass : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> {


    IBOutlet UINavigationBar* TopNavbar;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Title;
    NSString *ImageName;

    UIImageView *imageView;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *ImageName;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Title;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UINavigationBar* TopNavbar;
- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender;

@end
```

NextClass.m file

```
    #import "NextClass.h"

    @implementation NextClass
    @synthesize TopNavbar,scrollView,Title,ImageName,imageView;
    CGPoint newCenter;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Code for Managing Scrolling of Image.{#DR#-13/02/2012}
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES; 
    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:ImageName];

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (image.size.width),image.size.height )];

    [imageView setImage:image];

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    for(UIView *subview in [scrollView subviews]) 
    {
        newCenter=scrollView.center;
        newCenter=CGPointMake(scrollView.center.x, imageView.frame.size.height/2);
        subview.center=newCenter;
    }

    [imageView release];


}

- (IBAction)dismissView:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}



- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.TopNavbar =nil;
    self.scrollView=nil;
    self.Title=nil;

}


- (void)dealloc {

    if (ImageName) {
        [ImageName release];
        ImageName=nil;
    }
    if (Title) {
        [Title release];
        Title=nil;
    }
    if (scrollView) {
        [scrollView release];
        scrollView=nil;
    }
    if (TopNavbar) {
        [TopNavbar release];
        TopNavbar=nil;
    }

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Instruments Tool of Xcode producing following leaks but I'm not able to find out actual problem in my code.

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
GeneralBlock-48 7   < multiple >    336 libsystem_c.dylib   strdup
GeneralBlock-48     0x360c140   48  libsystem_c.dylib   strdup
GeneralBlock-48     0x360a060   48  libsystem_c.dylib   strdup
GeneralBlock-48     0x1b79e0    48  libsystem_c.dylib   strdup
GeneralBlock-48     0x1b79e0    48  libsystem_c.dylib   strdup
GeneralBlock-48     0x1ad910    48  libsystem_c.dylib   strdup
GeneralBlock-48     0x14e5a0    48  libsystem_c.dylib   strdup
GeneralBlock-48     0x14e5a0    48  libsystem_c.dylib   strdup
```

Thanks

Comment: Instead of imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; use self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init]; because you are already retaining it.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious.  You might try changing one line to `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *ImageName;` and see if it helps but I'm not convinced that it should.

Comment: sorry guys, your suggestions are not working.

Answer (score 0):

You never free the property "imageView". You problem is exactly why ARC was invented (and we've all had similar issues) - you should switch as soon as you can and never look back!)

Comment: I think I see a release to balance the alloc.  (Though it **would** be nicer if people made use of properties once they define them.)